# Hibernate manual and auto-generated primary key

Tags: sql, hibernate, jpa, orm, primary-key

I am having a requirement where if the user enters value for the primary key, then I need to use that when creating an entity and if in case the user does not provide value, the primary key needs to be auto-generated like R00001, R0002 etc.I would like to know how I could achieve this and any guidance on that

Answer (score 1):

Try to take advantage of the `IdentifierGenerator` interface and define an implementation of your own.

```
public class MyEntityIdGenerator implements IdentifierGenerator{

    public Serializable generate(SessionImplementor session, Object object)
            throws HibernateException {
         MyEntity entity = (MyEntity)object;

         if(entity.getId()==null){
            Connection con = session.connection();
            // retrieve next sequence val from database for example

            return nextSeqValue;
         }
    }
}
```

Then add appropriate annotations on the id field in your entity:

```
@Id
@GenericGenerator(name="myCustomGen", strategy="com.example.MyEntityGenerator")
@GeneratedValue(generator="myCustomGen")
```